# Microsoft access subqueries

Tags: ms-access

- product table: productid,productname

  - Delivered_item: numberorder,productid,qtyordered
  - product_issued: productid,qtyissued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i.itemNo, Sum(d.qtyordered) AS SumOfqtyordered, 
Sum(iss.qtyissued) AS SumOfqtyissued, 
Sum(r.qtyreturn) AS SumOfqtyreturn, 
(Sum(d.qtyordered)-Sum(iss.qtyissued)+Sum(r.qtyreturn)) AS Balance
FROM item AS i, delivered_item AS d, item_return AS r, item_issued AS iss
WHERE i.itemno=d.itemno 
AND d.itemno=r.itemno
AND iss.itemno=i.itemno
GROUP BY i.itemNo;
```

Simpler syntax, I hate select statements inside of Joins

**Edit**

Sorry I didn't realize you had one-to-many relationship

```
SELECT i.itemNo, TotalOrdered, TotalReturned, TotalIssued,       
(TotalOrdered - TotalIssued + TotalReturned) as Balance
FROM (( item i
INNER JOIN
(   SELECT itemno,          Sum(qtyordered) as TotalOrdered
   FROM delivered_item
   GROUP BY itemno
) as d ON d.itemno = i.itemno)
INNER JOIN
(   SELECT itemno,          Sum(qtyreturn) as TotalReturned
   FROM item_return
   GROUP BY itemno
) as r ON d.itemno = r.itemno)
INNER JOIN
(   SELECT itemno,          Sum(qtyissued) as TotalIssued
   FROM item_issued
   GROUP BY itemno
) as iss ON iss.itemno = i.itemno
```

This is the code from the other answer, fixed to MS Access' sql format, without syntax errors and tested

**Edit2**

If you want a product to show even if it's not in all the tables use LEFT joins :

```
SELECT i.itemNo, Nz(TotalOrdered,0), Nz(TotalReturned,0), Nz(TotalIssued,0), 
(Nz(TotalOrdered,0)-Nz(TotalIssued,0)+Nz(TotalReturned,0)) AS Balance
FROM ((item AS i 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyordered) AS TotalOrdered FROM delivered_item 
GROUP BY itemno)  AS d ON d.itemno=i.itemno)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyreturn) AS TotalReturned FROM item_return 
GROUP BY itemno)  AS r ON r.itemno=i.itemno)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT itemno, Sum(qtyissued) AS TotalIssued FROM item_issued 
GROUP BY itemno)  AS iss ON iss.itemno=i.itemno;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT itemNo, TotalOrdered, TotalReturned, TotalIssued,
       (TotalOrdered - TotalIssued + TotalReturned) Balance
FROM item i
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT itemno,
          Sum(qtyordered) TotalOrdered
   FROM delivered_item
   GROUP BY itemno
) d ON d.itemno = i.itemno
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT itemno,
          Sum(qtyreturned) TotalReturned
   FROM item_return
   GROUP BY itemno
) r ON d.itemno = r.itemno
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT itemno,
          Sum(qtyissued) TotalIssued
   FROM item_issued
   GROUP BY itemno
) iss ON iss.itemno = i.itemno
```